# AJAX call requires double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've created a function which loads content and writes into html. For some reason the function is displayed after two clicks instead of one. Any idea how to make it so it load and display the info with just one click?

```
function getFuncDoc(funcName, targetDivId) {
    var webServiceCall = funcName;
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: webServiceCall,

        success: function(doc) {
           $('#' + targetDivId).load(doc, function(){
            $('#' + targetDivId).toggle(                                   
                    function() {

                        $('#' + targetDivId).css('padding', '10px');
                        $('#' + targetDivId).html(doc);
                    });
           });
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            return 'Error';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem wouldn't be in your ajax code, it would be in the code that binds to the mouse event. Can you show us this code?

Comment: @quoo its a div that has an onclick property which then calls the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the targeted element (`targetDivId`) has `display:none` **before** the `toggle()` is triggered.

If that's **not the case,** then you'll need to **add this attribute** to your element in CSS.

`toggle()`-ing an element with `display:block` or `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` **will hide the element** and set its attribute to `display:none`, hence why you need to trigger it twice for the content to be shown.

Here is a [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tVJuk/).